# How can I resolve "UserWarning: The palette list has more values (10) than needed (4), which may not be intended"?

Tags: python, seaborn, warnings, palette

I am using "tab10" palette because of its distinct colors blue, green, orange and red.

```
k_clust = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state= 35, n_init=1).fit(df_normal)

palette = sns.color_palette("tab10")
sns.pairplot(new_df, hue="clusters", palette=palette)
```

The number of clusters are only 4 and the palette "tab10" has more than 4 colors. Is there a way to address this UserWarning?

The output is:

```
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:1507: UserWarning: The palette list has more values (10) than needed (4), which may not be intended.
  func(x=vector, **plot_kwargs)
```

Comment: As shown in these duplicates, [How to make a color map with many unique colors in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68209351/7758804) and [Seaborn palettes - prevent recycling of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26301347/7758804), set `n_colors=`: `palette = sns.color_palette("tab10", n_colors=4))`. Don't know why it was unduped, because the question boils down to, _how do I set the number of colors in the palette_.

Comment: I would vote as duplicate again. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom caused undupe and reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs for `color_palette()` say](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html#seaborn-color-palette) that you can pass `n_colors=4` to the call.

Try this:

```py
...
palette = sns.color_palette("tab10", n_colors=4) # equal to n_clusters
...
```